# Collision not detected correctly with multi-geometry shapes

Tags: ios, swift, game-physics, blender, scenekit

I have a spaceship object which has a complex geometry, and since SceneKit's physics doesn't work with complex bodies, I have adopted a workaround: I'm using some basic shapes like cylinders and cubes so simulate the whole spaceship's body. In Blender I created a set of objects that approximate the shape of the spaceship:

[image]

Then when I load the scene I remove these objects, but use their geometry to construct a *SCNPhysicsShape* to be used as the physics body of the spaceship:

```
// First I retrieve all of these bodies, which I named "Body1" up to 9: 
let bodies = _scene.rootNode.childNodes(passingTest: { (node:SCNNode, stop:UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Bool in
    if let name = node.name
    {
        return name.contains("Body")
    }
    return false
})

// Then I create an array of SCNPhysicsShape objects, and an array
// containing the transformation associated to each shape
var shapes = [SCNPhysicsShape]()
var transforms = [NSValue]()
for body in bodies
{
    shapes.append(SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: body.geometry!, options: nil))
    transforms.append(NSValue(scnMatrix4:body.transform))
    // I remove it from the scene because it shouldn't be visible, as it has 
    // the sole goal is simulating the spaceship's physics
    body.removeFromParentNode()  
}

// Finally I create a SCNPhysicsShape that contains all of the shapes
let shape = SCNPhysicsShape(shapes: shapes, transforms: transforms)
let body = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .dynamic, shape: shape)
body.isAffectedByGravity = false
body.categoryBitMask = SpaceshipCategory
body.collisionBitMask = 0
body.contactTestBitMask = RockCategory
self.spaceship.physicsBody = body
```

The *SCNPhysicsShape* object should contain all the shapes that I created in the Blender file. But when I test the program, the spaceship just behaves like an empty body, and collisions are not detected.

**PS**: my goal is only to detect collisions. I don't want the physics engine to simulate physics.

Comment: I doubt anyone else has tried what you're doing. Few people use SceneKit. Even fewer seem to use it for games. Someone else having imported bodies for physics is unlikely. I think you'll need to provide a sample, packaged project, for the two or three SceneKit employees that hang out here. They are probably the only people that can help with this.

Comment: If you take a look at the guys that answer a lot of SceneKit questions, you'll be able to figure out who they are, I think. And you have such an enormous amount of rep that you can probably start a chatroom with them, or some other means of direct communication.

Comment: @Confused And what do you suggest to use for games?

Comment: Depends on the game, target platform, team, time, etc etc. I like SceneKit, personally, because it's light and launches very fast. But it's limited by Apple's disdain for taking it seriously and committing to it. Which is a great shame, because the guys that work on it seem very talented. And they're French! Which is always cool.

Comment: The sad thing is you're probably doing something simple wrong, but that there's probably only 3 people in the world that could identify it.

Comment: And that there's no documents to guide you through doing this sort of thing. That's a real pity. I wish they'd hire someone to document their engines, at the very least.

Answer (score 3):

You want to use a concave shape for your ship. Example below. In order to use concave your body must be static or kinematic. Kinematic is ideal for animated objects.

**No need for:**

```
body.collisionBitMask = 0
```

A contact bit mask is all you will need for contact only.

**The code below should work for what you are looking for. This is swift 3 code fyi.**

```
let body = SCNPhysicsBodyType.kinematic
let shape = SCNPhysicsShape(node: spaceship, options: [SCNPhysicsShape.Option.type: SCNPhysicsShape.ShapeType.concavePolyhedron])
spaceship.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: body, shape: shape)
```

Without seeing your bit mask, I am unable to tell if you are handling those properly.  You should have something like:

```
spaceship.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = 1 << 1
```

**Anything you want to contact your spaceship should have:**

```
otherObject.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = 1 << 1
```

This will only register a contact of the "otherObject" to the "spaceship" and not the "spaceship" to the "otherObject".  So make sure your physics world contact delegate is handled that way or vise versa.  No need for both objects to look for each other.  That would be less efficient.

**Example of delegate below:**

```
func physicsWorld(_ world: SCNPhysicsWorld, didBegin contact: SCNPhysicsContact) {

    var tempOtherObject: SCNNode!
    var tempSpaceship: SCNNode!

    // This will assign the tempOtherObject and tempSpaceship to the proper contact nodes
    if contact.nodeA.node == otherObject {
        tempOtherObject = contact.nodeA
        tempSpaceship = contact.nodeB
    }else{
        tempOtherObject = contact.nodeB
        tempSpaceship = contact.nodeA
    }

    print("tempOtherObject = ", tempOtherObject)
    print("tempSpaceship = ", tempSpaceship)

}
```